# Serving Flutter web app from Phoenix, get SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

Tags: json, flutter, phoenix-framework

I have been trying to serve a flutter web app from a phoenix server. When I run them separately, they work fine. But when I compile flutter and put it in `priv/static`, the browser gives an error about `SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'`. I have read that this is commonly caused by the server routing incorrectly and serving an HTML page instead of JSON.

In the network tab, all of the assets load fine, except for `main.dart.js`. This file throws an the error on this line: `try{p=JSON.parse(a)}catch(r){s=A.az(r)`. My flutter app is not making any connections to the server besides loading itself (i.e. no API calls), so I have been struggling to fix the error.

This is the code for the page controller

```
defmodule Website45sWeb.PageController do
  use Website45sWeb, :controller

  def index(conn, _params) do
    conn
    |> put_resp_content_type("text/html")
    |> send_file(200, "#{:code.priv_dir(:website_45s)}/static/web/index.html")
  end
end
```

The catch all at the bottom of router.ex

```
  # flutter routes
  scope "/", Website45sWeb do
    pipe_through :static

    get "/*path", PageController, :index
  end
```

The definiton of :static

```
  pipeline :static do
    plug Plug.Static,
      at: "/",
      from: :website_45s,
      gzip: false,
      only: ~w(index.html flutter.js main.dart.js)
  end
```

These are the phoenix server logs when I go to /register (the only page being served currently).
The server does not display any errors. I removed some of the logs that were unnecessary.

```
[info] GET /register
[debug] Processing with Website45sWeb.PageController.index/2
  Parameters: %{"path" => ["register"]}
  Pipelines: [:static]

[info] GET /flutter.js
[debug] Processing with Website45sWeb.PageController.index/2
  Parameters: %{"path" => ["flutter.js"]}
  Pipelines: [:static]


[info] GET /icons/favicon.ico
[info] GET /flutter_service_worker.js
[debug] Processing with Website45sWeb.PageController.index/2
  Parameters: %{"path" => ["icons", "favicon.ico"]}
  Pipelines: [:static]
[debug] Processing with Website45sWeb.PageController.index/2
  Parameters: %{"path" => ["flutter_service_worker.js"], "v" => "3919904037"}
  Pipelines: [:static]

[info] GET /main.dart.js
[debug] Processing with Website45sWeb.PageController.index/2
  Parameters: %{"path" => ["main.dart.js"]}
  Pipelines: [:static]

[info] GET /assets/FontManifest.json
[debug] Processing with Website45sWeb.PageController.index/2
  Parameters: %{"path" => ["assets", "FontManifest.json"]}
  Pipelines: [:static]
```

I'd greatly appreciate any help.